# Regex to remove carriage return and line feed from lines with specified text

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression to remove the carriage return and line feed at the end of lines with specific text (or that start with specific text).

Can anyone get me started down that path?

Comment: [Regular Expressions Tutorial](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) and [RegExr is an online tool to learn, build, & test Regular Expressions](https://regexr.com/)

Comment: What tool(s) are you willing to use? This is important because (1) there are different flavors of regular expressions (although it may not matter in this case); (2) regex is to *match*; a way to *remove* something may depend on the tool; (3) with some tools removing line endings may not be as easy as removing printable characters.

Comment: Depending on your language/tool, you can do: Find: `\R` or `\r\n`, Replace: `Whatever you want`

Comment: I'm using Notepad++, 7.8.6 if version matters.  Thanks for asking further.

Comment: I only want to remove the \r\n from lines containing specified text.  If that helps any.